Deadpool-postgres connection
I'm using axum + deadpool-postgres to connect to database. In all examples I saw (like in deadpool-repo) people using axum's .with_state() with Pool. I've created async function that returns Pool, so it doesn't even compile. And I found only one solution - use Extension for this.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.
UPD: code sample with error mismatched types expected unit type '()' found struct 'deadpool::managed::Pool<Manager>'
//main.rs
let (router, api) = OpenApiRouter::with_openapi(ApiDoc::openapi())
        .nest("/test", test_routes())
        .with_state(database_pool().await) //here is the error
        .split_for_parts();
...
//test.rs
pub fn test_routes() -> OpenApiRouter<()> {
    OpenApiRouter::new()
    .routes(routes!(test_post_1, test_post_2))
}


Provide the code, compile time errors, runtime errrors, any resources referenced,  etc.

@TimsibAdnap I've solved the first problem. Im too inexperienced xD
So, I provided a code sample for second problem. Could u check it?

Does the router returned by test_routes() have type OpenApiRouter<deadpool::managed::Pool<Manager>> or OpenApiRouter<()>? Also add the test_routes() function signature to the code in question

@TimsibAdnap I added test_routes() code. And no, returned router doesn't contains any of this types. I even tried examples, but they dont work. Maybe there is some difference between axum's router and OpenApiRouter?

since the test_routes() return with generic (), it means that it takes no state, instead change the generic to deadpool::managed::Pool<Manager> in the test_routes(), then it will work as expected.

@TimsibAdnap thanks, it's worked! If u want, u can type your answer and I'll mark it as a solution!

If you convert the () from the generic of the OpenApiRouter in test_routes() to Pool<Manager>, it makes the with_state(...) expect Pool<Manager> instead of ().
// main.rs
let (router, api) = OpenApiRouter::with_openapi(ApiDoc::openapi())
        .nest("/test", test_routes())
        .with_state(database_pool().await)
        .split_for_parts();

//test.rs
pub fn test_routes() -> OpenApiRouter<deadpool::managed::Pool<Manager>> {
    OpenApiRouter::new()
    .routes(routes!(test_post_1, test_post_2))
}

